# Floating point formats and isinf()

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, ieee-754

I am currently dealing with floating point values in C++.
Consider the following c++ snippet:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long double num;

    // Set num to a large, valid, floating point value
    memset(&num, 0xcc, sizeof(num));

    std::cout << "num = " << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "isinf(num) = " << isinf(num) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::isinf(num) = " << std::isinf(num) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double), this creates an 80 bit [extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) floating point value, as I am using GCC on an x86 machine. The floating point value is therefore `0xcccc cccc cccc cccc cccc` and should be valid value.

Interestingly, the output is as follows:

```
num = -4.77987e+986
isinf(num) = 1
std::isinf(num) = 0
```

This makes me wonder:

- Why behave `isinf` and `std::isinf` differently? And which one is to be trusted?
- [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isinf/) it says that in C99, isinf is a macro, while in C++11, it became a function. However, when i compile the example e.g. with `-std=c++98`, i still get the same behavior. Shouldn't `std::isinf` not even be defined in that case?
- In general, how can i tell which floating point format my compiler/architecture uses?

Comment: What compiler version are you using? I get an error using gcc 6.20, and clang on OS X gives `isinf(num) = 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isinf`, the function from `cmath` intended for compatibility with the C language, takes a `double`. Your `long double` argument is silently converted to `double` when passed to that function. The conversion to `double` produces `+inf` according to the floating-point rounding rules (any number larger than a limit itself slightly larger than `DBL_MAX` gets rounded to `+inf`).

By contrast, `std::isinf` is [overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf) and can take a `long double`. When you pass it a `long double`, the argument is not converted and `std::isinf` can tell that it is not infinite.

---

To try to answer your other questions:

- it is a small detail whether `isinf` is a macro or a function. Knowing that it is a macro is only convenient for programmers who want to `#undef` it. Whether it is a function or is guaranteed to be a macro, it behaves the same (converts its argument to `double`).
- `DBL_MAX` and `LDBL_MAX` from `float.h`/`cfloat` are sufficiently indicative to distinguish between IEEE 754 double-precision (64-bit format) or the extended 80-bit format. You can also look at additional macros, such as `DBL_MANT_DIG` and `LDBL_MANT_DIG`, if you want to be certain that your code recognizes, say, quad-precision in 20 years when widespread processors implement it (this is not the case in 2017). It is not recommended to look at `sizeof(long double)` because this value can be 10, 12 or 16 for the 80-bit floating-point format depending on how much the compiler pads it, and the value 16 could also indicate quad-precision.

Comment: For C++, [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is normally preferred over C macros, and is extensible to other floating point types which might appear.

Comment: "`isinf`, ...takes a double. " is unclear.  At least in C, it is `int isinf(real-floating x)`  Maybe this is tied up in the meaning of  _semantic type_  in "First, an argument represented in a format wider than its semantic type is converted to its semantic type"  C11 7.12.3.3 2

Comment: @Bob__ sorry, you seem to have accidentally posted your comment about the question under my answer